# Время ожидания апи запроса

Tags: api, fetch, setinterval, settimeout

Мне нужно, чтобы апи поочередно, например, с интервалом в 20 секунд запрашивалось, может быть больше постов в одной ссылке. Как мне это организовать?

```
//ссылки
var firsturl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
var secondurl  ='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/';

var status = function (response) {
    if (response.status !== 200) { // если все ок (код 200)
      return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
    }
    return Promise.resolve(response);
  };
  var json = function (response) {
    return response.json();
  };
  

//функция, вызывающая fetch
async function hi(){
    
    try{
         let url1 = firsturl;
         let url2 = secondurl;
                fetching(url1);
                fetching(url2);
        }
     catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
hi();



function fetching(url){
    fetch(url)
    .then(status)
    .then(json)  
    .then(function (data) { 
       console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error', error); // если есть какие-то ошибки
});
}
```

Comment: setTimeout(hi, 10 * 60); ?

Comment: Adelya, самый просто вариант бесконечный цикл и Sleep(20 сек) и выход из цикла по критерию ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то....

Перенесем необходимые ссылки, для проверки, в массив, тогда:

```
let urls = [
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/'
]; // Это хранилище ссылок.

var index = 0; //Индекс текущей ссылки

//Далее берем этот массив и проходимся по нему.
var idInterval =  setInterval(processUrl, 20 * 1000);
function processUrl (){
    if (urls[index] === undefined){
        //Если ссылки закончились
        clearInterval(idInterval);
        return;
    }
    let url = urls[index];

    fetching(url);//Тут у нас запрос
    index++;
}
```